# Redux Toolkit action fetch

Tags: redux, react-redux

I want to add a fetch method inside of redux action. How can I make it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tjqe.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a reducer, not an action. It is not allowed to have side effects. You would either use an asyncThunk or RTK Query for that.

There are multiple chapters on API interaction in the official Redux Tutorial, I would recommend going at least through chapters 5, 7 and 8 that cover this topic with different approaches and perspectives: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts